# access vba hperling wont work

Tags: vba

```
 Dim dbs As DAO.Database
 Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("יומן תקלות")
    Dim str As String
   rst.MoveFirst

    Do Until rst.EOF
          If IsNull(rst!אישור) Then
               str = rst![מס' תקלה]
               rst.Edit
          rst!אישור = "C:\test\pic\" + str + ".jpg"
          rst.Update
          End If
       rst.MoveNext
    Loop
```

i have this code and it work perfect
but when im trying to press the hyperlink nothing heppned
the path is ok and also the file name
i tried to rightClick->hyperling->open hyperling and nothng also
please help me

Comment: In what way is this connected to opening a hyperlink?

Comment: Oh now I see, I was misunderstanding due to the title. Is the column in your table set to hyperlink? If it is, try using a query to update the records.

Comment: i dont want query to uptade them... this short vba do this allready and this is in AutoExe...

Comment: and in the table i see the links and the hand pointer are appears on it but when i click nothing happend

Comment: Well, if 'Nothing' happens, not even an error message of any kind, I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

If clicking the link throws an error, it is because the link provided is incorrect, but since nothing happens, the problem is probably caused by a wrong datatype in your table.

Go to the design view of your table, and set the datatype to *Hyperlink*.

Comment: it is
if i enter the path+filename manual by writing or copy past it will work